Darken/thicken all the text in a pdf
Is there a way to darken/thicken all the text in a pdf? I just want to slightly increase the weight.* Not all pdf viewers render the same. Foxit renders thicker than Okular. Adobe Acrobat renders the lightest. I want something which shall render like Preview on MacOS, which renders it very thick. Firefox and Chrome render it slightly blurry. So are some parameters which I can change in order to modify the appearance of a compiled pdf? I want to do it for an already compiled pdf, whose source code is not available.
*Many of the digitizations of the fonts, such as Times or Garamond, it seems, were designed from the metal sorts, and not from the printed output. The printed output is slightly thicker due to the spreading of ink. Thus, the digitizations are often anemic. the Same holds true for Computer Modern. Even though Computer Modern was designed digitally, it was created for viewing when printed, not on screen. And the original font offered 'modes' to modify the font according to one's printer. Unfortunately, all the vectorized clones of Computer Modern (except two modern ones) are very thin. This font is very popular when it comes to typesetting mathematical texts, the texts that I am most interested in reading.
Edit: Added a real world example in response to a comment. Take any document created using LaTeX. For example this unofficial reference manual for LaTeX2e: https://texdoc.org/serve/latex2e.pdf/0.

@KJ I see. Can you please share how you did it? I don't want to thicken them a lot, just a little. For example, the New Computer Modern fonts offer two weights, Regular and Book. The Book weight is what I am looking for. Most importantly, both the weights are metrically compatible with each other. So, just replacing all the glyphs from the Regular weight to the Book weight won't affect the document at all, in absolute terms.

Is there a parameter which one can modify to thicken the vector shapes? I am sure with some trial and error, I shall be able to find a sweet spot. And I mostly want to read documents this one font, so I can spend some time on it.

@KJ Does one need any paid software like Adobe Acrobat Editor for it?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is a challenging area for bulk changing PDF and not all documents will likely need the same approach. If we simply change lines up or down in thickness we can watch the command line results. So first ignore text we can change generic page "stroke" thickness.
Here the rectangles (excluding text) can be altered at will.
Initially reduced to 0.1 wide.

Increased to 2.1 wide

With Text outlines it is less easy we need to trigger the page not the text to stroke the text outlines. The first problem is how to detect and alter page mediadata. Here the page data streams go straight to the /Fonts, so we need to inject black outline thickness here.
The combination of page components need to include, colors, a width & "2 Tr"
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 RG 
0.1 w
2 Tr

The simplest way to see where the page data text boundary is will be to use QPDF decompression in QDF mode.
qpdf\bin>qpdf --qdf --decrypt --object-streams=disable --compress-streams=n texin.pdf texout.qdf

TEXOUT.QDF  (Avoid disturbing the critical number after the /F as they are different.)

This can be done with any suitable find and replace tool but few text editors can work with binary files (Notepad++ is a good programmers editor) Here I am using Hxd, on a 6 page document.

We need to fix the edits back from a binary.QDF to a PDF file. and use the thinline upwards to thicken the text outlines.
fix-qdf texout.qdf >texout.pdf
cpdf -thinlines 0.5 texout.pdf -o latex.pdf 

Now both the text outline and line work will both appear thicker.


Hey, thank you so much for your help. Sorry to reply late. I was out of station today. But I've found a fairly easy method. It requires only Inkscape, which is freely available for Windows, MacOS and Linux. We just open/import the pdf file in inkscape, and select the options to convert all the fonts to paths. Then, simply adjust the stroke width. Very easy. I shall shortly write an answer. The downside is that for very big pdfs, it takes a lot of time.

Hey, I was finally able to achieve what I wanted using PDF XChange Editor (the paid version). It is very easy to do so. It also preserves all the existing pdf structure, such as bookmarks, and links. Thank you so much for mentioning this editor.
